# Warnings on TeXShop Console (XeTeX)

Tags: warnings

```
LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
* 
* Redefining document command \oldstylenums with arg. spec. 'm' on line 128.

LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
* 
* Redefining document command \textsubscript with arg. spec. 's' on line 25.

LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
* 
* Redefining document command \textsuperscript with arg. spec. 's' on line 28.
```

what *does* that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you probably have

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

in your preamble. This uses fontspec-patches.sty which includes

```
\RenewDocumentCommand \oldstylenums {m}
{
{ \addfontfeature{Numbers=OldStyle} #1 }
}
```

Basically, this ensures that commands designed for use with the standard LaTeX font set up continue to behave as expected when fonts are instead selected using the interface provided by fontspec. It thus stops stuff breaking unexpectedly when people switch from (pdf)LaTeX to Xe/LuaLaTeX.

I am also guessing that you have

```
\usepackage{realscripts}
```

in your preamble or that you are using another package which itself calls realscripts. For example,

```
\usepackage{xltxtra}
```

has the effect of requesting realscripts because xltxtra.sty includes the line

```
\RequirePackage{realscripts}
```

realscripts.sty includes the lines

```
\RenewDocumentCommand \textsubscript {s} {
    \IfBooleanTF #1 \fakesubscript \realsubscript
}
\RenewDocumentCommand \textsuperscript {s} {
    \IfBooleanTF #1 \fakesuperscript \realsuperscript
}
```

Again, these definitions keep stuff working as expected. This time the point of the re-definitions is to use the real superscript/subscript figures provided by fonts when these are available without breaking functionality in the case of fonts which don't have these features.

The warnings are there just to tell you this is happening. It means that if weird stuff happens, you know which definitions got changed by which packages and can use this information in troubleshooting.

EDITED to cover the possibility of loading realscripts *indirectly*.

Comment: Uh-huh. Yes `fontspec`, no `realscripts` though. I have: `\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathtools,mathdots,mathptmx}
\usepackage{letltxmacro,nicefrac,xfrac}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode,color,textcomp,hyperref,graphicx}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=3.5cm, outer=4cm, inner=4cm, marginparsep=0.7cm, marginparwidth=1.5cm]{geometry}`

Comment: Nonetheless if I run xelatex on a document which loads just those packages, it loads realscripts. So even though you may not have \usepackage{realscripts}, one of the packages you call directly must request it so that you are indirectly requesting it. Try putting \listfiles at the top of your source to get a full listing of the files xelatex is using. EDIT: xltxtra.sty requires it.